# Can I declare a user defined function in structured text in studio 5000?

Tags: function, plc, structured-text

I am used to python syntax:

def function(par1, par2)
Body of function here
Return result

Does ST allow user defined functions like this? I am using studio 5000.

Comment: Are you familiar with AOIs?

Comment: Yes love them. Use them any time possible. Do you know if this is the only possible way to declare functions? in Studio 5000? I know Codesys allows for declaring functions, but not seeing any other way other than AOI as you mentioned.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, AOIs are the only option in Studio 5000. Allen Bradley seems resistant to fully implementing IEC 61131

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but result only in function parameters passed as InOut. Function result can be only boolean and means EnableOut.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29801166)